# Combine a sequence of LineString

Tags: java, gis, geotools

I have a sequence of LineString, for example `lineString1` and `lineString2` [image]

where `lineString1.getEndPoint() == lineString2.getStartPoint()` or 
`lineString1.getStartPoint() == lineString2.getEndPoint()`
I want to get `LineString` object (not `MultiLineString`) which would be combined of `lineString1` and `lineString2`.

I didn't find any good solution to do it.

Comment: `ineString1.getEndPoint() == lineString1.getStartPoint()` are you sure you didn't mean `lineString2.getStartPoint()` ?

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [JTS `LineMerger`](http://javadox.com/com.vividsolutions/jts/1.13/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/linemerge/LineMerger.html) to achieve this, it returns a `Collection<LineString>` but in your example this is a single line as they join (in other cases only some of the lines may touch).

```
import java.util.Collection;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.ParseException;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.io.WKTReader;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.operation.linemerge.LineMerger;

public class LineJoin {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    /*String[] WKTS = { "LINESTRING (254058.76074485347 475001.2186020431, 255351.04293761664 474966.9279243938)",
        "LINESTRING (255351.04293761664 474966.9279243938, 255529.29662365236 474272.4599921228)",
        "LINESTRING (255529.29662365236 474272.4599921228, 256166.05830998957 473979.44920198264)",
        "LINESTRING (256166.05830998957 473979.44920198264, 256082.8878282134 472762.2531920295)",
        "LINESTRING (256082.8878282134 472762.2531920295, 254245.37250651795 472802.681197444)",
        "LINESTRING (254245.37250651795 472802.681197444, 254294.87550167093 473782.10435392085)",
        "LINESTRING (255802.5570897992 475306.663459122, 256973.3861333156 473826.71649389854)",
        "LINESTRING (256973.3861333156 473826.71649389854, 256996.781511873 472271.0759416939)",
        "LINESTRING (254134.08645022905 471750.25133671844, 253091.20265363617 473772.75685744354)",
        "LINESTRING (252764.19811300343 475015.97340571403, 253526.90397945273 476194.3201198712)",
        "LINESTRING (253526.90397945273 476194.3201198712, 254983.29259833007 475930.5996061625)" };*/
    String[] WKTS = {"LINESTRING(10 40,11 41)","LINESTRING(11 41,12 42)"};
    WKTReader reader = new WKTReader();
    LineMerger merger = new LineMerger();
    for (String wkt : WKTS) {
      Geometry geom = reader.read(wkt);
      merger.add(geom);
    }

    Collection<LineString> collection = merger.getMergedLineStrings();

    for (LineString l : collection) {
      System.out.println(l);
    }
  }

}
```

For your test inputs it gives:

```
LINESTRING (10 40, 11 41, 12 42)
```

For the commented out WKT you would get:

```
LINESTRING (252764.19811300343 475015.97340571403, 253526.90397945273 476194.3201198712, 254983.29259833007 475930.5996061625)
LINESTRING (254134.08645022905 471750.25133671844, 253091.20265363617 473772.75685744354)
LINESTRING (254058.76074485347 475001.2186020431, 255351.04293761664 474966.9279243938, 255529.29662365236 474272.4599921228, 256166.05830998957 473979.44920198264, 256082.8878282134 472762.2531920295, 254245.37250651795 472802.681197444, 254294.87550167093 473782.10435392085)
LINESTRING (255802.5570897992 475306.663459122, 256973.3861333156 473826.71649389854, 256996.781511873 472271.0759416939)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah, it works with LineMerger class :)

Answer (score 0):

Following [geotool documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/opengis/geometry/coordinate/LineString.html):

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
LineString combinedLineString = GeometryFactory.createLineString(
    lineString1.getControlPoints()
        .addAll(lineString2.getControlPoints())
    );
```

Comment: It'll work only if lineString contain 2 Poins - start and end. But mostly it contains several Points where LineString not is just a plain line.

Comment: It'll be cool to have method something like 
`geometryFactory.createLineString(MultiLineString)`

Comment: then is `combinedLineString = GeometryFactory.createLineString(lineString1.getControlPoints().addAll(lineString2.getControlPoints()));` a solution ?

Comment: Will this solution actually work with JTS LineString?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`union`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#union()) method of `GeometryCollection` to join the LineStrings. See the documentation [here](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jts/combine.html) - for a collection of line strings it has effect of fully noding and dissolving the linework.

```
static Geometry combineIntoOneGeometry( Collection<Geometry> geometryCollection ){
     GeometryFactory factory = FactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory( null );

     // note the following geometry collection may be invalid (say with overlapping polygons)
     GeometryCollection geometryCollection =
          (GeometryCollection) factory.buildGeometry( geometryCollection );

     return geometryCollection.union();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks but 'union' is not exactly what I need.
I've done it by checking start and end coordinated of 2 lineStrings to find the common one.
If needed - I'll make `(LineString) lineGeometry.reverse();` after that just put all coordinates to array:
`coordinates.addAll(Arrays.asList(lineGeometry.getCoordinates()));`
and after all build combined LineString object:
`geometryFactory.createLineString(coordinates.toArray(new Coordinate[0]));`

Comment: I've tested `combineIntoOneGeometry` method. Unfortunately it returns `MultiLineString` - not combined 1 single LineString. I've write simple test:
`LineString lineString1 = (LineString)getGeometry("LINESTRING(10 40,11 41)");
        LineString lineString2 = (LineString)getGeometry("LINESTRING(11 41,12 42)");
        Collection<Geometry> geometries = new ArrayList<>();
        geometries.addAll(getGeometries(lineString1));
        geometries.addAll(getGeometries(lineString2));
        Geometry geometry = combineIntoOneGeometry(geometries);
        System.out.println(geometry);`

Comment: Over on gis.stackexchange, Ian answered [a similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197485/how-to-combine-linestrings-using-jts), where the difference between union and line merging is explained in more detail.